# Show figures two at a time by default

Tags: graphics

I'm writing a document that has a lot of figures, and as a result is quickly growing in size. I want to bring the page count down if possible, and I'd like to do it by placing the figures side by side.

I know I can do it manually by using two minipages inside a figure, but I want latex to place them for me, since I don't really care what figures are placed side by side.

Setting `width=0.45\textwidth` made it smaller, but it didn't get the figures to go side by side, even without centering them.

Is there any way to set this up by default?

The environment I'm using:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure
\end{document}
```

I don't want someone to write code for me, I just need a starting point for where to look.

Comment: I don't understand how I can give a mwe for this, it's a conceptual question (as are a lot of the questions I ask and people ask for a mwe). If you really want one, then no I haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start.

Comment: You can use the `subfigure` environment from the `subcaption` package, if the figures side by side are to be considered  as subfigures of a main figure. If they're supposed to be independent figures, there's the `floatrow` package.

Comment: You mentioned in your question "Setting width=0.45\textwidth made it smaller, but it didn't get the figures to go side by side, even without centering them.". Can you create an MWE that reproduces this (ie. what you tried)? At the very least, give us a compilable document with `example-image`s so it saves us some work.

Comment: I've added an example, however I don't want someone to go write code for me, I just wanted an idea where to start. I'm looking into floatrow now. Thank you

Comment: It seems that the question is about how merge two figure's environments in one (side by side).

Comment: Yes @touhami (I think the same too): I have some ideas but the problem is that if the last figure (odd) is in another chapter or section has to be alone and not paired with next chapters. Can still be done... but it is more complicated.

Comment: I would be fine if occasionally the figures were independent. I was primarily looking for a space saving strategy (to cut on printing) and figured this would be the best one

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354726/117534

Comment: you can redefine figure's environment so that it write it's contents to a file and input this file. the point is the first figure start writing and begin the environment and the second figure stop writing and input the file.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, i.e., a macro named `\twofigures`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for "\includegraphics" macro
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand\twofigures[6]{%
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip}
   \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}
     \caption{#2}\label{#3}
   \end{minipage}\hfill
   \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#4}
     \caption{#5}\label{#6}
   \end{minipage}
\end{figure}}

\begin{document}
\twofigures%
     {example-image-a}       % name of image file
     {Left-hand-side figure} % caption
     {fig:left}              % argument for "\label"
     {example-image-b}
     {Right-hand-side figure} 
     {fig:right}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is nice, but I don't know if it's what I want (I don't think what I want is possible). The issue is that I still have to tell the macro which two figures I want. What I would like is to be able to place all my figures and just tell float that it's okay to place them side by side (kinda like an additional option to `[htbp]`

Comment: @BrydonGibson - I don't think that what you describe is possible, at least not without some very serious hacking of LaTeX's float-placement algorithm. For instance, the float-placement algorithm is designed to be "greedy", i.e., to always try to output the accumulated list of floats (which may contain just 1 float) as soon as it can, *without* looking ahead in the document to check if there's another `float` waiting to join the list. To begin with, then, one would have to provide a workable alternative to the "greedy" setup -- easier said than done, right?!

Comment: I didn't even think of that, and it's good point, so I guess without some serious work it can't be done, and it's not worth it for the application. Thanks for trying!